# C# File Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I've got a class with a method "GetNewsFeed", that when a page is requested:

- Check to see if a file exists & it is less than 30 minutes old

  - If it **does** exist, read contents of the file, push contents onto page
  - If it **does not** exist, go to a URL and write the contents of that page to a .txt file, push contents onto page

I am not very well versed with C#, so I'm trying to cobble together a few sources. I believe I am close, but I'm unable to get the files to refresh every 30 minutes if needed (I'm not getting any compliation errors or anything). Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static string GetNewsFeed(string url, string fileName)
{
    // Set the path to the cache file
    String filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/cachefeed/" + fileName + ".txt");
    string fileContents = "";

    // If the file exists & is less than 30 minutes old, read from the file.
    if (File.Exists(filePath) && (File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath) > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30)))
    {
        fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }

    else
    {
        try
        {
            // If the file is older than 30 minutes, go out and download a fresh copy
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                // Delete and write the file again
                fileContents = client.DownloadString(url);
                File.Delete(filePath);
                File.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContents);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            }
        }
    }

    return fileContents;
}
```

Finally, I've got some code elsewhere that will read these text files and manipulate their contents onto the page. I don't have any issues with this.

Comment: A bit vague, I'm afraid.  Have you stepped this in debug to know where things might be going wrong?  Perhaps the date comparison is flawed?

Comment: If you have an exception downloading the string and you never have a file then the method will always return an empty string.

Comment: You could also use [ASP's cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx) and set the expiration date to 30 minutes from now.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I was going to ask if there was a specific reason not to use the ASP.NET Cache.

Comment: @PhilPursglove There wasn't a specific reason other than I'm not familiar with ASP.NET Cache.

Answer (score 4):

Odds are, you're catching an exception in the else block and it's only returning the fileContents. Try putting a breakpoint in the exception block to see what is going on.

You'll need to change it to:

```
 catch( Exception e )
```

in order to get this information.

Also, you don't need this:

```
            File.Delete(filePath);
```

The WriteAllText method will overwrite the file that is already there. Try removing that line and check your directory permissions.

You may also want to change

```
 (File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath) > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30)))
```

to

```
 (DateTime.Now - File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath)).TotalMinutes > 30
```

Comment: This makes sense. I modified the few suggestions you had; thank you. I put a breakpoint on the opening curly brace on the catch, but didn't get any errors. I even went so far as to remove the try; catch; block, and I'm still getting my page to load, but it's not updating the file (I also changed from 30 min to 1 min for testing). Any thoughts?

Comment: Put a breakpoint here: File.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContents); What's the filePath and fileContents?

Comment: They are what I expect (a path to the txt file and a JSON object). However the txt file modified date hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `throw` to my `catch` and believe it or not, one of the URL's I was passing into my method was invalid. So yes, the culprit in my code was the catch statement.

I fixed this and all is working properly.

Thanks for the tips everyone.